# Desconfiguración de la variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE (irreparable)

Tags: django, ubuntu, configuración

El caso es que tengo un VPS en Digital Ocean con Ubuntu 18.04. Instalé todo lo necesario comenzando con el tipico apt update y upgrade, después pip, virtualenvwrapper, django y postgresql, inicié con runserver y probé en el navegador la página de prueba de django y django-admin, todo perfecto durante unos días. 
Después de unos días, volvía a actualizar mi sistema con apt update y upgrade, y la aplicación de django dejó de funcionar, con el error **"You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings."**
He probado muchas cosas sin hallar la solución; he reinstalado virtualenvwraper, django, entornos virtuales y proyecto, pero sigue sin funcionar como antes.
También he probado a asignar la variable manualmente con **export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings** y da errores dice que no encuentra el módulo.
¿Alguna idea de lo que le ha ocurrido a mi sistema?
Me gustaría probar todas las posibilidades antes de borrar el droplet y volver a instalar todo.

Comment: FIjate en el archivo manage.py en la directiva `os.environ.setdefault`, el valor de `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` debe ser el `nombre-de-tu-proyecto.settings` `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project-name.settings")` No se si esta sea la causa, pero es algo relacionado con `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`

Comment: Ya lo miré, la variable indica el nombre de proyecto.settings correcto, como siempre. Tengo la impresión de que **sudo apt-get dist-upgrade** ha modificado alguna ruta o enlace para django o para el virtualwrapper, y por eso no la encuentra. Solo marca el error de esta variable si uso el comando **django-admin**, si lo hago con **python manage.py** no, pero tampoco funciona en el navegador.

Comment: MIra [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082128/improperlyconfigured-you-must-either-define-the-environment-variable-django-set) Al igual que en el `manage.py`, examina lo mismo en el archivo `wsgi.py`, que este bien la directiva `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` . Por otra parte, **estas usando vitualenvwrapper?** Debes definir la variable de entorno  `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="nombre-proyecto.settings"` en la ruta `.virtualenvs/nombreentornovirtual/bin` creería que eso ya lo tienes
 `

Answer (score 1):

Pido disculpas por mi FALLO DE NOVATO, acostumbrado a trabajar en local, olvidaba asignar la Ip de mi servidor al final de **python manage.py runserver 15.15.15.15:8000** Lo siento, lo siento, lo siento.

Pero he aprendido una buena lección; si utilizamos django-admin debemos asignar la variable **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE** con anterioridad, algo que no logré conseguir con **export** pues me daba errores como comenté en los otros posts (no importa). Entonces es mejor utilizar **python manage.py** que de forma automática asigna esta variable por nosotros.